# Who rates my documents

Tags: 2010, rating

Just a quick question, is there any chance, how to get list of users, which rates items in one list, or documents in one library ? Maybe I only overlook something really obvious...

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

[`SocialRatingManager.GetRatings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee575644.aspx) can give you all Ratings for an Url or for a User.
See MSDN article [How to: Create and Retrieve a Social Rating for more info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407954.aspx) for more info on how to work with ratings programatically

To get all ratings for a single library you can use code like this:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Office.Server.SocialData;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities;

namespace SharePointConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var url = "http://sp2010/TestDocs";
            using (var site = new SPSite(url))
            {
                var sc = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);
                var sm = new SocialRatingManager(sc);
                using (var web = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    var list = web.GetList(url);
                    foreach (SPListItem item in list.Items)
                    {
                        foreach (var rating in sm.GetRatings(new Uri(SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl(site.MakeFullUrl(web.ServerRelativeUrl), item.Url))))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("{0} rated {1} to {2}", rating.Owner.DisplayName, rating.Url, rating.Rating);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how can i convert it to web part for appear in dashboards?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a powershell with foreach for a site collection or a web and get a output text file.

```
# get the site collection
$s = get-spsite http://siteurl 

# loop through all site in the site collection, 
# then through all lists / libraries in that site (filtering out everything but actual doc libs 
# (The catalog filter excludes all sharepoint libs like the masterpage catalog etc.
// for each list, add a folder called test to the rootfolder
$s.AllWebs | Foreach-Object { 
  $_.Lists | Where { ($_.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary") -and ($_.BaseTemplate -notmatch "Catalog") } | Foreach-Object {
    # Do your code here and if u need to include basetype do so
    # 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Ken! Can you write me the BaseType and Template for lists please? I'm not able to get list of users for list objects.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see code to retrieve information about ratings in your PS script.