# viewing user ratings on items?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, rating

There is a rating feature on the list that I have turned on. But am interested in knowing how I could see what people are rating an item.
So if an item has had 20 people rate it I might just be interested in what the manager rated it?
Is this something you can do with the rating feature?

I am using SharePoint Enterprise on premise

Comment: As far as i know there are four columns gets created on the list when we enable ratings ('Number of likes, Number of ratings,Rated By,Liked By'). Rated By stores the list of users rated, and 'Number Of Ratings' holds an integer. So there is no column that stores the 'user and rating' value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on SP 2013, you can turn the ratings to likes and you can see who liked the item by hovering over the smile.

It is not that easy for star ratings, here is a page that gives you some hints

[Who rates my documents](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/39880/who-rates-my-documents?rq=1)

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/sharepoint/en-US/d8fb12b5-64ad-4476-bf38-a8c995502352/find-out-who-has-rated-a-sharepoint-2010-list